# I can't backup my settings (and apps)

Tags: 8.1, backup

When I try to backup my settings on my Lumia 830 running WP 8.1 GDR2, after the upload bar reaches 100%, I always get the message:

> "There was a problem backing up your settings. Try again later."

This error doesn't depend on the network connection I'm using (4G or WiFi).

I already tried to delete old backups and/or to backup only the Settings.

[image: Screenshot of backup settings]

Comment: I assume you've tried the weird stuff like restarting? Trying while plugged in vs. on battery?

Comment: @Shawn I just tried with no success.

Comment: Have you checked the existing backups to make sure that it really hasn't succeeded, and the phone isn't just throwing a weird error?